Mismatch in scikit-learn's RANSAC inlier/outlier classification
RANSAC plot
For the RANSAC algorithm, I would like to implement a residual threshold based on the NMAD value, calculated separately for my dataset. However, when I plot the results, I notice that the RANSAC algorithm does not perform well, as it misclassifies inliers as outliers and vice versa. To better understand the errors, I also plot the upper and lower boundaries of the chosen threshold. What could be going wrong?
x_for_RANSAC = df_orig['median'].to_numpy()
y_for_RANSAC = df_super['median'].to_numpy()
                      
mask = ~np.isnan(x_for_RANSAC) & ~np.isnan(y_for_RANSAC) & ~np.isnan(error_bars)
x_for_RANSAC = x_for_RANSAC[mask]
y_for_RANSAC = y_for_RANSAC[mask]
nmad = median_abs_deviation(y_for_RANSAC, scale='normal')
ransac = linear_model.RANSACRegressor(residual_threshold = nmad)
ransac.fit(x_for_RANSAC.reshape((x_for_RANSAC.size,1)),y_for_RANSAC.reshape((y_for_RANSAC.size,1)))
inlier_mask = ransac.inlier_mask_
outlier_mask = np.logical_not(inlier_mask)
line_X = np.linspace(x_for_RANSAC.min(), x_for_RANSAC.max(),endpoint=True)[:,np.newaxis]
line_y_ransac = ransac.predict(line_X)
              
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
ax = fig.gca()
ax.axis('equal')
plt.title('Naples',weight='bold', fontsize=25)
plt.plot(x_for_RANSAC[inlier_mask], y_for_RANSAC[inlier_mask], 'bo', label='inliers')
plt.plot(x_for_RANSAC[outlier_mask], y_for_RANSAC[outlier_mask], 'bx', label='outliers')
plt.ylabel('Super resolved median LST [°C]',weight='bold', fontsize=25)
plt.xlabel('Original LST [°C]', weight='bold', fontsize=25)
plt.plot(line_X,line_y_ransac,'r--',label="RANSAC regressor: Y = "+ format(ransac.estimator_.coef_[0][0],'.2f')+' X + '+format(ransac.estimator_.intercept_[0],'.2f'))
upper_boundary = line_y_ransac + nmad
lower_boundary = line_y_ransac - nmad
plt.plot(line_X, upper_boundary, 'g--', label="Inlier boundary (Upper)")
plt.plot(line_X, lower_boundary, 'g--', label="Inlier boundary (Lower)") 
plt.plot(line_X,line_X,'k-',label="Expected: Y = X")
ax.grid(which='minor', alpha=0.2)
ax.grid(which='major', alpha=0.5)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=20)         
plt.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=20)
plt.savefig(output_path+date+'_'+ 'scatter_plot.png')

